# write plug-in system in c++

Tags: c++, linux, plugins

Good time of day! Prompt please me, where can I find information about creating a system of plug-ins in C + +? linux

Comment: Not a real question and no emphasis on any effort on your part either... voting to close...

Comment: When I ask what is you're OS, you can add a "linux" tag and **make a full sentence** not just a single word. It seems like you don't want to spend some time trying to write a pleasant question so I will not spend any more time trying to make a complete answer.

Comment: "where can I find information about creating a system of plug-ins" ever heard about http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=active&q=c%2B%2B+plugin+system&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai= ?

Answer (score 3):

It highly depends on your OS, but the principle is always the same:

Usually, your program load one or several dynamic libraries - the plugins - (`.dll` files on windows, `.so` on *nix) that have the same public interface (the same set of functions, with identical names and parameters).

By the way, those libraries do not require to be written in C++: you may create your main program using C++ then create a plugin using Delphi. As long as the public interface remains the same, it's all fine.

You didn't gave use enough information to be more specific.

What OS are you targetting ?

Comment: Doesn't that also require the shared libraries to use the same calling convention as C/C++ does on the platform?

Comment: @Asmageddon: Indeed. Also there is the problem of the runtime one links to.

Comment: Hmm, so basically, if I want to, I can use a custom-ish calling convention for my language and provide some C externs if I want to, right? Though I think it's not going to differ much, and not at all if I can do a thing I'm thinking of without that. For the note, I want multiple return values via tuples, and to be able to put functions returning anything at all into * -> Void function pointers.